# Authenticating machine using Azure AD

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-active-directory

I need to authenticate equipment, using Azure AD.

As I understand it, I cannot use Azure AD as a Domain Controller, but can I install on an Azure VM and use that as a controller?

Comment: Joey, can you expand on what you mean by authenticate equipment? What's the goal? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's correct.  Here's an [article](http://windowsitpro.com/identity-management/windows-azure-active-directory-vs-windows-server-active-directory) that describes the difference between Active Directory DS and Azure AD.
[image: AD DS AAD venn diagram]

Also, here's Microsoft's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151466.aspx) on deploying AD DS on an Azure VM.